# Twitter API in Python

Tags: python, api, twitter

I am trying to access the Twitter API via Python and export the tweets into a csv, but it seems to just keep loading. I am getting no errors but I just want to make sure that the code is working:

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
access_token=''
access_secret=''
consumer_key=''
consumer_secret=''
class listener(StreamListener):
def on_data(self,data):
    try:
        print(data)
        with open('TwitterAPI.csv','a')as f:
            f.write(data)
    except Exception as e: 
        print('[!]Error: %s' %e)
        return(True)
    def on_error(self,status):
        print(status)
auth=OAuthHandler(consumer_key,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)
twitterStream=Stream(auth,listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["pythontweets"])
```